# jQuery.get - how to get text instead of html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have following code to get data from other site:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp text"
});
jQuery.get(url, function(rawContent) {
    console.log(rawContent);
});
```

But I got a error: "Syntax error" from jQuery, becouse target site use following doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

How can I get text by this query instead of html?

Comment: Look up jQuery parameters.  Im fairly certain you could say:  "contentType":"text/plain"  or similar.   See: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Fallenreaper — That's what the `dataType` is for.

Comment: Oh yea!   Forgot.  Derp.  contentType is outbound.  +1 to you

Comment: Wait, are you doing JSONP? JSONP requires a lot of cooperation between the outside server and yours. If their syntax is not 100%-perfect JS syntax (JSON with JS padding) then you can't use JSONP. Consider using the Allow-Origin headers from that server to permit the request instead.

Comment: you have to mention `dataType:"text"` in your call

Comment: Rak, `DataType` accepts 1 item, not 2.  You should narrow it to json, jsonp, xml, script, html, or text, etc

Comment: @Fallenreaper It accepts multiple _space_ separated strings

Comment: @Fallenreaper — No, you can specify a space separated list to do funky conversion stuff. `"jsonp text"` is still wrong in this case though.

Comment: Guys, if I use just "text" or "html", I got following error: cross domain requests not allowed. When I use "script" or "html", I got a "Syntax error"

Comment: @Rakshazi — You've run into the same origin policy. You can't instruct your visitors' browsers to fetch content from other websites and make it available to your JS without the other site co-operating.

Comment: @Quentin - ok, how can I bypass this? May be use iframe or something else (One of variants - use "proxing" script, eg: PHP script, which will get data from selected url and return it to user, but it is the worst way, I need to to all on the user-side)?

Comment: @Rakshazi — There is no way to do it on the client side. If you don't have the co-operation of the other site then a proxy is your only option.

Comment: @Quentin ok, please, post this comment as answer, i'll check it as solution

Comment: @Rakshazi — That comment isn't actually an answer to the question you originally asked. My existing answer is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dataType: "jsonp text"` is telling it to parse a response as JSONP and then convert it to text. The The response you describe is not JSONP.

Just use `dataType: "text"`.

Comment: please, read this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783015/jquery-get-how-to-get-text-instead-of-html#comment38461638_24783015